# Is this the correct convergence interval and radius of power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, solution-verification

I was requested to find convergence interval and radius of

$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{e^n}{n^3}(4-x)^n$$

First of all, see that

$$a_n=\frac{e^n}{n^3}(4-x)^n=\frac{(e(4-x))^n}{n^3}=\frac{(e*-(x-4))^n}{n^3}=\frac{(-e)^n}{n^3}(x-4)^n$$

so that

$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{e^n}{n^3}(4-x)^n=\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{(-e)^n}{n^3}(x-4)^n$$

We therefore have a power series centered at $4$.

$a)$ Take $$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|\frac{(-e)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}(x-4)^{n+1}*\frac{n^3}{(-e)^n(x-4)^n}|=|e(x-4)(\frac{n}{n+1})^3|$$

so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=e|x-4|$

$b)$ Because $e|x-4|<1$ we have that the series converges for $|x-4|<\frac{1}{e}$, and its radius is $R=\frac{1}{e}$. I will skip this to keep this short, but it is not hard to show that $|x-4|<\frac{1}{e} \iff x\in (4-\frac{1}{e}, 4+\frac{1}{e})$. (The fact that the serie converges for $x=c=4$ is important.)

If we examine the boundaries of the interval, we'll see that for $x=4-\frac{1}{e}$, we have a $p$ series with $p>1$ and it converges.

For $x=4+\frac{1}{e}$ we have an alternating series with $b_n=\frac{1}{n^3}$, where $b_n$ is decreasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = 0$. Therefore, according to the alternating series test, it converges.

(I don't show this because it's as trivial as replacing $x$ with the values and see what we get; don't want to make this too long for anyone to read.)

Therefore the interval of convergence is $[4-\frac{1}{e}, 4+\frac{1}{e}]$ and $R=\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: I agree with almost everything, except I don't see what you assert the radius of convergence is $3$?

Comment: @Bernard I'm quite sure that the OP meant $\frac1e$ instead of $\frac13$.

Comment: aren't you missing parens?  $(-e)^n$ instead of $-e^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, I ment $\frac{1}{e}$, it was a typo! And yes, David, I'll fix the parens-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the radius of convergence is $\frac1e$ and the interval of convergence is $\left[4-\frac1e,4+\frac1e\right]$. You can prove that your series converges at both points $4\pm\frac1e$ by noting that if $x$ is any of these points, then$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\lvert\frac{e^n}{n^3}(4-x)^n\right\rvert=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^3},$$which converges. So, your series converges absolutely when $x=4\pm\frac1e$.

Comment: Thank you very much, José!